Looking for a sufficiently official resource defining the connected components of level sets
I am currently writing a decent amount having to do with differential geometry and the level sets of (hyper)surfaces and have several instances of functions having distinctly separate curves in a given level set, e.g. two separate circles. If I'm lucky, a level set describing $z=f(\vec{x})$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ may be parameterized such that the set can be written as $s(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$. In some cases, there may be multiple parameterizations, i.e. $s_1(t),s_2(t),...,s_k(t)$, where these collections of distinct parametric functions compose the level set. From very limited research/googling I've found these distinct/separate curves of a level set being referenced as "connected components." However, I have not found any super official sources using this expression, only forum posts and blog-like sites. I would like to know if anyone has a more official source (e.g. an academic journal article,textbook,etc) using and defining this expression. I would mostly like to know if a "component" is still a "connected component" even if it has some asymptotic aspect. For example, take $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}-1$. This can be written in polar coordinates as $r(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta)+z$, therefore it can be put in parametric form as $(x(t),y(t)) = (\cos(t)\sec^{2}(t),\sin(t)\sec^{2}(t))$, where, for $t \in [0,2\pi)$, it clearly as asymptotes at $t=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$, splitting the level set, singularly described by $(x(t),y(t))$, into two distinct/disconnected parts. Would these two distinct parts be different connected components or the same connected component? They certainly are not connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$, however, they are both described using a single parametric function. This is the main inquiry that has me looking for a sufficiently official source where a formal definition might illuminate an answer to my question. You may answer my question directly if you know it, but I'm primarily here looking for a source that answers it.

Connectedness is a topological notion - so in your example there are two connected components even though one parametric equation describes both of them.

@Karl Thank you! Topology and its corresponding definitions are very low on my list of areas of math I've experienced. You wouldn't happen to know if there is a term or expression to refer to these distinct parametric functions, would you?

A single parametric function with very disconnected domain.
